# How to convert unix dates from mongodb into y-m-d format in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, date, datetime

So when I print the value of the variable using this code

```
print(i['due_date'])
```

the result is

```
{'$date': 1506988800000}
```

This date is equivalent to

```
ISODate("2015-10-03T00:00:00Z")
```

I tried to convert 1506988800000 online and it gives me a result of

```
Sat, 29 Jul 49724 00:00:00 GMT
```

which is wrong, I remove the 3 zeros on 1506988800000, changing it into 1506988800, gives me the correct result

```
Tue, 03 Oct 2017 00:00:00 GMT
```

The info above is just to show you that the i['due_date'] contains time and can produce inaccurate result on conversion of date.

My question is how can I convert the 1506988800000 into y-m-d WITHOUT the time (date only). I've search a lot and still I cannot convert it successfully.

I tried this code

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i['due_date']['$date'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but it gives me an error of

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Thanks in advance for those can help!

EDIT

```
        skip    = (int(self.request.POST.get('current')) - 1) * int(self.request.POST.get('rowCount'))
        limit   = int(self.request.POST.get('rowCount'))
        doc     = Bill.objects().skip(skip).limit(limit)
        total   = Bill.objects().count()
        raw     = json.loads(doc.to_json())
        row     = []

    for i in raw:
        i['id'] = i['_id']['$oid']
        i['invoice'] = i['invoice_no']
        i['amount'] = i['amount']
        i['amount'] = "{0:.2f}".format(i['amount'])
        i['amount'] = float(i['amount'])
        i['amount'] = "{:,}".format(i['amount'])
        i['amount'] = "P"+i['amount']
        # how to convert the date to string in y-m-d? i['due_date']
        i['action'] = '<button class="btn bgm-blue" onclick="viewBill(\''+i['id']+'\')"><i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i></button>'

        row.append(i)
```

Comment: It's already a [`datetime`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/datetimes.html) object when retrieved from MongoDB.

Comment: So just do `print(i['due_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`. You are confusing the BSON serialization with the access of the actual data,

Comment: @NeilLunn it produce an error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: How about you show the full example of you are retrieving the data and iterating the cursor. Bottom line here is if the `mongo` shell says `ISODate()` then the python driver is going to make that a `datetime` when it is read.

Comment: I've already edit it, the reason why it is structured like that is because I'm using jquery bootgrid.

Comment: Don't do this `raw     = json.loads(doc.to_json())` instead just use the `doc` which is actually a "cursor". `for i in doc:` Then everything is all fine.

Comment: It produce an error, raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: '_id'

Comment: Of course it does. You can't keep all the same code. Just only attempt to print out the date like I showed you as the only code in the loop. Then work it out. It's not hard, just think.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you it works!!!